# Redirect output to HTML using flask

Tags: python, html, flask

I am trying to connect to DB and show some data on webpage, below is what i tried:

```
import jaydebeapi
import jpype
import sys
from flask import Flask
from flask import request, render_template
app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/')
def my_form():
    return render_template('Name.html')

@app.route('/', methods=['POST'])
def teradataconn():
    classpath="/export/home/tdgssconfig.jar:/export/home/terajdbc4.jar"
    Name = request.form['Name']
    query="select top 1 Col1, Col2, Col3 from TABLE where Col2='Name' and Col3 is null order by Col1 desc"
    jvm_path=jpype.getDefaultJVMPath()
    jpype.startJVM(jpype.getDefaultJVMPath(), "-Djava.class.path=%s" % classpath)
    conn=jaydebeapi.connect('com.teradata.jdbc.TeraDriver', 'jdbc:teradata://HostName/DATABASE=DBNAME,USER=USER_NAME,PASSWORD=PassWord')
    cursor=conn.cursor()
    cursor.execute(query)
    rows=cursor.fetchall()
    conn.close()
    return render_template('output.html',rows=rows)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run
```

Below is the page (Name.html) to enter Name which will be processed against DB.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<body>
    <h1>Enter JC Name</h1>
    <form action="." method="POST">
        <input type="text" name="Name">
        <input type="submit">
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Below is for displaying output (output.html):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<body>
    <p>{{ rows }}<p>
</body>
</html>
```

After i enter the Name on first page, i get below output. Please suggest what needs to be done to fix it.

```
Bad Request

The browser (or proxy) sent a request that this server could not understand.
```

I removed below line and hardcoded the value and i was getting the result, so it seems value is not getting passed, any suggestions please.

```
Name = request.form['Name']
```

Comment: I dont think you can have two routes the same like that ....

Comment: @JoranBeasley I want to show output on HTML, how can i achieve that ?

Comment: Before attempting to access `request.form['Name']`, try printing `request.form`. Let us know what shows up in the console or error logs.

Comment: @JoranBeasley Actually, you *can* bind the same URL rule to different view functions provided they use different `method`s. In my tests, when the `method`s *are* the same, the first route declared is used.

Comment: @this-vidor i tried as you said, nothing different on UI but on server console i got
`IP Address - - [20/Jul/2016 23:04:16] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 -
ImmutableMultiDict([('text', u'Name I passed on WebPage'), ('my-form', u'Send')])
IP Address - - [20/Jul/2016 23:04:20] "POST / HTTP/1.1" 400 -`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the output of `print request.form`, your trouble is not in Flask, but in your form submission. Flask is a receiving a form with key-value pairs: `text:someName` and `my-form:Send`.

(Flask will return a `400 Bad Request` error if you attempt to access a property of `request.form` that does not exist; [see docs](http://werkzeug.pocoo.org/docs/0.11/datastructures/#werkzeug.datastructures.MultiDict). In this case, you are attemting access the property `Name`.)

The second pair results from the fact that you have given `name` and `value` attributes to your `submit` input. There is no need for this! You can declare that element simply: `<input type="submit">`.

As for the first `<input>`, it is bizarre that it is sending the `type` attribute instead of the `name` attribute as the key. I am unable to re-create the issue. Make sure that in your HTML your element is really declared `<input type="text" name="Name">`, and not `<input type="text" name="text">`.

Comment: I have updated the html file as asked but still i  get same Bad Request message, below is message on console.
`IP Address - - [21/Jul/2016 00:18:59] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 -
ImmutableMultiDict([('Name', u'Name I passed on WebPage')])
IP Address - - [21/Jul/2016 00:19:01] "POST / HTTP/1.1" 400 -` I have updated my question with the html i am using currently.

Comment: @ankitpandey And you're sure that when you replace the line `Name = request.form['Name']` with `Name='someName'`, the error disappears?

Comment: Its working now, there was some other issue as well which is fixed now, thanks a lot for your help @this-vidor

Answer (score -1):

```
@app.route('/', methods = ['GET','POST'])
def my_form():
    if request.method='GET':
        return render_template('Name.html')
    if request.method='POST':
        classpath="/export/home/tdgssconfig.jar:/export/home/terajdbc4.jar"
        Name = request.form['Name']
        query="select top 1 Col1, Col2, Col3 from TABLE where Col2='Name' and Col3 is null order by Col1 desc"
        jvm_path=jpype.getDefaultJVMPath()
        jpype.startJVM(jpype.getDefaultJVMPath(), "-Djava.class.path=%s" % classpath)
        conn=jaydebeapi.connect('com.teradata.jdbc.TeraDriver', 'jdbc:teradata://HostName/DATABASE=DBNAME,USER=USER_NAME,PASSWORD=PassWord')
        cursor=conn.cursor()
        cursor.execute(query)
        rows=cursor.fetchall()
        conn.close()
        return render_template('output.html',rows=rows)
```

Comment: i tried it but it is also not working. I am getting same error.

Comment: Downvote: Since this solution includes no comments or explanation, I have no idea why you believe this re-organization of the `GET` request handler would fix a `Bad Request` error triggered by `POST` requests.

Comment: @this-vidor apologies, I had added text also before but it probably got deleted when I was pasting the code.

Comment: @SahilAgarwal Not a matter of apology! If you fix up your answer I'll remove the downvote. The goal here is useful answers.